# Approximating a fitting image size

Tags: java, c, image, algorithm, pseudocode

The solution I am aiming for does select the best fitting image size from a given number of sizes.

Given a number of rather random resolutions, I would like to find an image sized as close as possible to my preferred size.

Suppose I would like to use an image sized width x height (`preferredImageSize`).

Example: 320x200

Suppose I have the following image sizes at my disposal (`availableImageSize`) width1 x height1, width2 x height2, ... (maybe up to 10 different sizes).

Examples: 474x272, 474x310, 264x150, 226x128, 640x365, 474x410, 480x276, 256x144, 160x90, 320x182, 640x365, 192x108, 240x137, 480x276

For developing some generic approach to make the `preferredImageSize` variable I am trying to find a good solution that computes rather quick but also results into something that does *look good on the screen*.

I define *looks good on the screen* as an image that is:

1. hardly upscaled
2. as close to the given aspect-ratio (`preferredImageSize.width / preferredImageSize.height`) as possible
3. may be heavily downscaled
4. may be cropped/stretched in very small amounts

My initial (rather trivial) approach:

Run through the available image sizes once and find the smallest width delta (`abs(preferredImageSize.width - availableImageSize.width)`). The image with that smallest delta is then chosen (`bestFitWidth`).

That is certainly a way to solve the issue but definitely does not comply with my *looks good on the screen* hopes.

Any hints, no matter if text, source or links would be awesome. Ow, and if you think that my requirements (aka hopes) are already leading into the wrong direction, go ahead, let me know...

---

Edit: added cropping and stretching as options - which, I am afraid will make the issue even harder to solve. So if needed leave it out of the equation.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting your question... I find it very good... +1

Comment: I agree. I think this is a decent question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple "if/then" approach:**

I would do two things:

1. Since you would rather not upscale, but are OK with downscaling (which I find a good choice), NEVER use a source image that is smaller than your target, unless none is available.
2. Since "heavy" downscaling is OK, I would try to find an image that matches the aspect ratio as closely as possible, starting with the smallest acceptable image and going to progressively larger images.

To put it together, first throw out all images from the list that are smaller than your target. Then, start with the smallest image left and check its aspect ratio against your target. If the mismatch is acceptable (which you need to quantify), use the image, otherwise go to the next bigger one. If you don't find any acceptable ones, use the one with the best match.

If you've already thrown out all images as smaller than your target, you will likely end up with a bad-looking image either way, but you should then try out whether it is worse the use an image that requires more upscaling, or whether it is worse to use an image that is a worse aspect ratio match.

One other thing you need to think about is whether you want to stretch or crop the images to match your target aspect ratio.

**More complex quantitative approach:**

The most flexible approach, though, would be to define yourself a "penalty" function that depends on the size mismatch and the aspect ratio mismatch and then find the source image that gives you the lowest "penalty". This is what you have currently done and you've defined your penalty function as `abs(preferredImageSize.width - availableImageSize.width)`. You could go with something a little more complex, like for example:

```
width_diff  = preferredImageSize.width  - availableImageSize.width
height_diff = preferredImageSize.height - availableImageSize.height
if (width_diff > 0) width_penalty = upscale_penalty   * width_diff
               else width_penalty = downscale_penalty * width_diff
if (height_diff > 0) height_penalty = upscale_penalty   * height_diff
                else height_penalty = downscale_penalty * height_diff
aspect_penalty = ((preferredImageSize.width / preferredImageSize.height) - 
                  (availableImageSize.width / availableImageSize.height)) * stretch_penalty;
total_penalty = width_penalty + height_penalty + aspect_penalty;
```

Now you can play with the 3 numbers `upscale_penalty`, `downscale_penalty`, and `stretch_penalty` to give these three quality reducing operations different importance. Just try a couple of combinations and see which works best.

Comment: I do like that approach. I guess introducing a little weighting and playing with its values might actually do the trick. Thank you! +1

Comment: For now I implemented a solution that follows your idea of weighted error computation. For normalising the width/height errors, I divide  them by their preferred width/height (not exactly sure if that is a good idea). The chosen weights are; `upscaleWeight = 3.0f, downscalingWeight = 0.1f, aspectRatioWeight = 2.0f;`. Overall I think the results are pretty good now. Additionally, I added a dynamic-computing pattern to make sure that I do this computation only if a new size is given as  the input value. Thanks again!!